# Read file with unicode chars

Tags: java, nio

I want to read a file which have an HTML content like

```
<li> Face palm  </li>
<li> Ass spade card  </li>
<li> Water pistol   </li>
```

When I try to read the file with

`new String(Files.readAllBytes(expectedFilePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

I get for the first line `Face palm ߤ¦`  . So obviously the Unicode character `1F926` is not encoded correctly. Changing to `UTF_16` won't help much. How to read the file properly?

Comment: The code would correctly read UTF-8 encoded text. If it does not work, the file is not encoded in UTF-8. How did you check that it does not work?

Comment: Where are you printing the line you've read? I don't believe most terminals support unicode characters.

Comment: Uhu... I just see - it works - But Eclipse doesn't show the unicodes correctly. :-(